# Divide number by 2 using only addition and subtraction

Tags: math

I want to implement division by 2 using only + and -(preferably -). I know I could divide just by repeatedly subtracting, but this solution would be extremely slow for bigger numbers. I hope someone can help me with that.

My numbers can be anything from 0 to 255. I can add and subtract(suprisingly) and check if numbers are equal/greater/less etc. but I'd use comparision only when it would be unavoidable.

If addition overflows result will be 255. If subtraction underflows result will be 0.

Comment: Division can be implemented using subtraction; similarly, multiplication can be implemented using addition; similarly, exponentation (taking to a power) can be implemented using multiplication. In the case of exponentiation, there is an algorithm sometimes called [fast exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) that avoids multiplying repeatedly the naive way. You can inspire yourself from this algorithm; and modify it so that instead of exponentiating using multiplication, it divides using subtraction.

Comment: By "extremely slow" I suppose you mean O(n). Consider a simpler problem: what if you want to find the biggest power of two less than n?